# Is this Bilinear form inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

> $$Q(x,y)=x^{T}\begin{pmatrix} 
>      1      & 1 \\ 
>       1        & 2
>     \end{pmatrix} x$$

Can this Bilinear form be a inner product in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

It is easy to see it is symmetric, but how can I proof it is always positive?

Comment: A symmetric $2\times2$ matrix gives a positive definite form, iff its diagonal entries are positive, and its determinant is positive. Ok, if you are new to bilinear forms than that piece of information may not be very useful (in that your teacher may not appreciate the argument).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen so when do I need to check is the eigenvalues are positive?

Comment: Yes, that's equivalent to the form being positive definite (and works also for bigger square matrices).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen just to be sure also about $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 1):

x^2 + 2xy + 2y^2 = (x+y)^2 + y^2.